# SSRS Count Rows

Tags: reporting-services

I know variations of this question have been asked and I've read a lot of them but none of the solutions seem to work for me.  I'm trying to get a row count or total count of only the results in one column.  I can get a count using several different methods but only on the "dataset".  As you can see from the image I want to count the number of rows returned for spcc_parcel.  The counts I get now are wrong because I'm getting a total row count.  Is it possible to just count the result rows?

#### Report Builder Screen Shot

[image: Report Builder Screen Shot]

Comment: If you have the option this would probably be achieved easier by counting the results in your dataset query.

Comment: you said "I want to count the number of rows returned for spcc_parcel" but you are using a table right? is there some rows of spcc_parcel that are empty? because if you are using a table you could use =CountRows("DataSetName") to count the total rows of your dataset.

Answer (score 14):

This is how we count Total Records in our report

```
=CountRows("DataSetName")
```

Comment: Question. I want to get a count of rows, but only for the same ID, so that it is for those records, as this is a sub-report and it's for multiple "people".  I tried making a text box expression, like this: ="Person Contacts " & Fields!SQLRowCountValue.Value  & " of " & Sum(Fields!IDColumn.Value, "sp_rptMasterReport_TeamMember_Contacts") .  It ends up giving me the sum for all contacts for all members in all teams.  I am filtering the report to just 1 team, so I am listing each team member, and within that, there is contact info. I wanted to put "Person Contact 1 of 5" etc. What should I do?

Answer (score 2):

Try this =Count("Dataset Name") or =Count("Tablix Name")

Comment: =Count("Dataset Name") works but it's too broad and I get a higher count than than there are results.  For example, when I execute the report there are 128 result rows but I get a Count total of 132.

Comment: try DistinctCount instead of Count

Answer (score 2):

From the question you posted, according to best of my understanding you are trying to count only those rows in which some specific column (let's say column 1) have some value,

So in order to do that you can use the following expression.

```
=Sum(IIf(IsNothing(Fields!Column1.Value) , 1, 0), "DatasetName")
```

What this expression will do is it will add 1 to the total if there exists some value in the Column name specified or otherwise add zero, after doing that with every row in the result set it will display the total in the corresponding field.

Let me know if it works.